# assigning value to a variable twice in Python

Tags: python-3.x, variable-assignment

I saw this line in one of the source files of a Python package.

```
if   ("%s/" % base_iri) in PREDEFINED_ONTOLOGIES: 
    base_iri = base_iri = "%s/" % base_iri
```

What does it mean when there is a double assignment like here
`base_iri = base_iri = "%s/" % base_iri`? What will happen if I rewrite the line as `base_iri = "%s/" % base_iri`?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misread it? `base_iri = base_iri = "%s/" % base_iri` and `base_iri = "%s/" % base_iri` should be the same thing. It would be different if the names were different, but with the same names, it would just reassign the same data to the same name twice.

Comment: It's the same. Maybe typo or something

Comment: @Carcigenicate, yes, I am sure. In fact, I copy-pasted the line from the source code, so I could not possibly misread it. So, I guess, it must be just a matter of style then?

Comment: I wouldn't even call that a matter of style. I'd say that would be an error by the author. It doesn't serve a functional or stylistic purpose.